# How can I make one form constantly overlaying another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need form2 to be on top of form1 and at the same size and location of form1. Especially when form1's location changes. Simply, how do i get form2 to follow form1?

Comment: Why? I can't see a situation where this would be necessary. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: on form1 i have...scrolling text. Form2 contains an image that helps focus on the text in form1. I need form2 to follow form 1. Thanks

Comment: Why would you not just have another control on Form1?

Comment: I can't make a control transparent.

Comment: Use the Show(owner) overload and implement the LocationChanged event.  You'll have trouble with activation and interesting minimize animation on Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event of `form1` by adding an event handler either in the constructor or via the properties menu in Visual Studio and update the size and position of `form2` in that.

To add an event handler manually add the following in your constructor:

```
this.SizeChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.AlbumChooser_SizeChanged);
```

(If you just type `this.SizeChanged +=` then tab twice the rest of the line and the event handler method will be created for you). Then the handler will look like this:

```
    private void AlbumChooser_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Location = new Point(this.Location);
        ....
    }
```

You may also have to subscribe to the `ResizeEnd` event as well.

Comment: what do you mean by "subscribe" and how can this be achieved?

Comment: @Vlad - what technology are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Ok. But how exactly can i update the size and position i get errors such as "Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Location' because it is not a variable."

Comment: @Vlad - you should be able to.

Comment: when i write "form2." it doesn't give me the property "Location". When I write it out it underlines in red.

Comment: @Vlad - you have to have a reference to `form2` to do this.

Comment: how would that be accomplished? (Making the reference to form2)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the wrong solution. What I would do is create 2 [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx), one for your current `Form1` and one for your current `Form2`.

Put the scrolling text in `UserControl1` and the `Image` in `UserControl2`.

Add both of these User Controls to a form, overlapping, and change the visibility of the user controls instead of creating new forms. When swapping:

```
private void SwapVisibility() {
    UserControl1.Visible = !UserControl1.Visible;
    UserControl2.Visible = !UserControl2.Visible;
}
```

Set the `Visibile` property of `UserControl2` to `false` intially.